# How to copy *.csv to one txt file in same directory? Using PowerShell

Tags: file, powershell, csv, copy, text-files

In C:Temp I have 5 csv files, how I copy all to one file.txt?
Thanks
Josef

Answer (score 3):

If you know the names, you can get the content like this:

```
Get-Content c:\item1.csv, c:\item2.csv
# or
Get-Content c:\*.csv
```

The `Get-Content` command will read all the specified files and return it as array of strings. Note that you can specify encoding as well.

```
Get-Content -Encoding Utf8 c:\*.csv
```

(for more info see `Get-Help Get-Content -online` or `help gc -online`)

As for storing the content to the file, pipe the otput from `Get-Content` to `Set-Content`. You can specify encoding as well. I'm saying that because redirection (`>`) by default outputs the content as Unicode, which is not always wanted.

Long story short. Use:

```
Get-Content *.csv | Set-Content file.txt
```

---

You can of course use build-in cmdlets for working with CSV. First list the files and pipe to `Import-Csv`. This will produce an `PsObject` for each csv row. This is piped to `Export-CSv` to store it in a file:

```
Get-Item c:\csv1.csv, c:\csv2.csv | 
  Import-Csv | 
  Export-Csv c:\res.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cat *.csv > yourtxtfilename.txt
```

If you're just going to use the command prompt, replace `cat` with `type`.

The wildcard expansion order is undefined, so if the order is important you can specify it explicitly with:

```
cat file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, file4.csv, file5.csv > file1-5.csv
```

**cat** is an alias for **Get-Content**